# Updating a string in a for loop, used to be passed to system

Tags: c, terminal, command, openmp

I am working on Mac OSX and using bash in terminal. I am programming in C, and I am having problems using system() in a for loop. I realize what I am trying to do can be accomplished with a shell script, but I am trying to parallelize the process and currently I only know how to make that work with openmp programming in C.

The general idea is to call an executable, ./program, with three inputs for that program: an integer, a string and a double. I would like to call program 100 times with various inputs. Currently I am struck trying to figure out how to pass a string to system() that is updated by the for loop. I should note that the ("sub")string being used for the input is also being updated to get data from different folders (formatted as: folder0000, folder0001, etc.)!

My attempt goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int spot;
    double X;
    char command[50];

    #pragma omp parallel for private(command, path)
    for(X=0, spot=0; spot<100; X+=0.005, spot++){ 
        char path[50];
        strcpy(path, "/home/folder%04d", spot);
        strcpy(command, "./program %d %s %lf", 50, path, X);
        system(command);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One error that I get is obvious if you know how strcpy works (which I don't truly), is that I am passing it too many arguments. It only likes to take 2: strcpy(string 1, string 2). I was inspired to try this before understanding strcpy, by mimicking how to printf double, integers, etc.

Is this some other way I could accomplish what I am trying to do? Thanks for any help you guys can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [`sprintf(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/sprintf/):

```
sprintf(path, "/home/folder%04d", spot);
sprintf(command, "./program %d %s %lf", 50, path, X);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. I believe the program is working, however, I do not think it is running in parallel and this is something else I will need to look into...Thanks again for your help.